# How to get columns from other table with a foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "itemDetails"
(
    id smallint,
    name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    description character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE items
(
    id int,
    "detailsId" smallint REFERENCES "itemDetails" (id),
    "ownerId" int,   -- REFERENCES users (id),
    "condition" int NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The `itemDetails` table stores all the static information of an item, while the `items` table stores each individual instance of an item, with columns such as the `condition` and `ownerId`.

If I where to get all items owned by a user by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE "ownerId" = 5;
```

How would I get the name and description of those owned items using the foreign key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a plain join:

```
SELECT i.*, d.name, d.description
FROM   items i
JOIN   "itemDetails" d ON d.id = i."detailsId"
WHERE  "ownerId" = 5;
```

[Read the manual about the `FROM` clause here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Aside: Avoid double-quoted CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres. Makes your life easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: It works! And thanks for the tip, I will be sure to look into that.